# mixing css and less using webassets

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to mix file types and add filters with a single bundle e.g.

```
css = Bundle(
    'css/reset.css',
    'css/style.css',
    'css/fancybox.css',
    'css/custom.less',
    output='gen/packed.css',
    filters=['less']
)
```

I want all css and less outputed to the same file i.e. `gen/packed.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the bundle like this:

```
css = Bundle(
  'css/reset.css',
  'css/style.css',
  'css/fancybox.css',        
  Bundle('css/*.less', filters='less', debug=False)
  output='gen/packed.css'
)
```

http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/webassets/css_compilers.html